# Why did Kido accede to working for the Yakuza in SF?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-man-in-the-high-castle

Why did Kido accede to working for the Yakuza in SF in *The Man in the High Castle*?

1. Did he lack enough net worth to pay his son's debts? S4 exhibits him living in a typical high-rise apartment.
2. Even if he did, why didn't he seek assistance from the 3-star admiral whom he saved or the Crown Princess? Couldn't they have loaned him money, or at least goaded the Yakuza to waive his debt or allow more time for re-payment?

I don't think it's shameful to seek assistance when your son has PTSD caused by military service.

Answer (score 3):

After the Emperor of Japan ordered strategic withdrawal of all military and civilians to empty JPS (Japanese Pacific State) they didn't have anymore of authority in that region. Hence taking help from military or Crown Princess was out of question.

> Did he lack enough net worth to pay his son's debts?

After the evacuation the Japanese currency had no value in former JSP. The only thing that mattered was allegiance to the Yakuza for carrying out further operations to hold the region. Chief Inspector Kido had all the skills which the Yakuza could use. Hence they bartered his allegiance for his son's life.

Comment: Indeed, and both points are covered in the scene.